# H5py Unicode support for dictionaries

Tags: python, unicode, h5py

So, with h5py there is no support for unicode in attributes.  It throws the error: TypeError: No conversion path for dtype: dtype('

I have seen the recommended work-around which is to encode the strings before storing like so: (f.attrs['x'] = [a.encode('utf8') for a in mylist])

However, I do not understand how to encode them into strings when storing them in a dictionary.

My code is as follows:

with sess.as_default():

```
        if vae_checkpoint:
            print('Restoring VAE checkpoint: %s' % vae_checkpoint)
            saver.restore(sess, vae_checkpoint)

        nrof_images = len(image_list)
        nrof_batches = int(math.ceil(len(image_list) / args.batch_size))
        latent_vars = np.zeros((nrof_images, args.latent_var_size))
        attributes = np.zeros((nrof_images, nrof_attributes))
        for i in range(nrof_batches):
            start_time = time.time()
            latent_var_, attribs_, indices_ = sess.run([latent_var, attribs, indices])
            latent_vars[indices_,:] = latent_var_
            attributes[indices_,:] = attribs_
            duration = time.time() - start_time
            print('Batch %d/%d: %.3f seconds' % (i+1, nrof_batches, duration))
        # NOTE: This will print the 'Out of range' warning if the last batch is not full,
        #  as described by https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/8330

        # Calculate average change in the latent variable when each attribute changes
        attribute_vectors = np.zeros((nrof_attributes, args.latent_var_size), np.float32)
        for i in range(nrof_attributes):
            pos_idx = np.argwhere(attributes[:,i]==1)[:,0]
            neg_idx = np.argwhere(attributes[:,i]==-1)[:,0]
            pos_avg = np.mean(latent_vars[pos_idx,:], 0)
            neg_avg = np.mean(latent_vars[neg_idx,:], 0)
            attribute_vectors[i,:] = pos_avg - neg_avg

> filename = os.path.expanduser(args.output_filename)
>             print('Writing attribute vectors, latent variables and attributes to %s' % filename)
>             mdict = {'latent_vars':latent_vars, 'attributes':attributes, 
>                      'fields':fields, 'attribute_vectors':attribute_vectors }
>               with h5py.File(filename, 'w') as f:
>                 for key, value in iteritems(mdict):
>                     f.create_dataset(key, data=value)
```

How can you encode the strings when using the dictionary as above?
Python 3.3

Thanks,
Doug

Comment: It's the keys that are of type `str`, right? You can write `mdict('latent_vars'.encode('utf8'): latent_vars, ...`, but since you use ASCII only you can write byte literals instead: `mdict(b'latent_vars': latent_vars, ...`.

Comment: Thanks @lenz.  In this case, it's the data that I needed to encode. I use 'str' as that's what the h5py doc informs us to use for python3.

Comment: When you encode `str`, you get `bytes`. You cannot "encode into strings", unless "encoding" has a special meaning here.

Comment: Well, I'm going by the git comments for h5py, which states: **"This reflects the fact that at the moment there's no way to store the NumPy Unicode type. Briefly, h5py turns your list into an array of type "U", tries to store it and fails".**  So, they offer the work-around as: 1) " Explicitly encoding your strings before storing (f.attrs['x'] = [a.encode('utf8') for a in mylist])
2) Explicitly specifying a unicode string-vlen storage type for the attribute:
f.attrs.create('bar', [u'\u03b2', u'\u03b2', u'\u03b3'], dtype=h5py.special_dtype(vlen=unicode))   and I'm unsure of how to do that here

Comment: That means using `bytes`, not `str` (work-around 1). For me to help you, you need to show what are the values of `latent_vars`, `attributes`, `fields`, and `attribute_vectors`.

Comment: @lenz  Thanks. I've updated the code in the original post to include how it's generating the values. This is actually code from a git repo where the author didn't update or maybe didn't test the code for python 3. I've fixed a couple of items already but this one I just don't understand and there's no help from the author.

Comment: `latent_vars`, `attributes`, and `attribute_vectors` are all numeric, so this problem doesn't apply. `fields` is not shown.

Comment: so, 'fields' is a string. It's taken from a list in a text file that notes the attributes of the image. From the code: fields, attribs_dict = read_annotations(args.annotations_filename)  , which looks like 'hair_color eye_color beard' Are you saying that this is the only value that I need to encode this attribute as a string? When I posted my question on the h5py issue, they sent me to: https://github.com/h5py/h5py/issues/289

Comment: All values that are `str` (ie. Unicode strings) need to be encoded to `bytes` (byte strings). If you have an array of `str`, convert it to an array of `bytes`. That's what I understand.

Comment: @lenz Thanks for helping me through this. I truly appreciate it and hope it helps other. But could you provide me an example of how to do that within my code?  I tried 'mdict(b'latent_vars': latent_vars, ....' like you suggested, but still the same error. How do I properly convert it to an array of bytes in the code I have?

Comment: You said it's relevant for the values, not the keys of `mdict`, so `b'latent_vars'` should not be necessary. And you said `fields` is a string, so encode it (`fields.encode('utf8')`) to get a byte string. If you have a list of `str`, create a new list where each element is encoded (ie. of type `bytes`).

Comment: fields.encode('utf8')  returns 'object has no attribute 'encode'.

Comment: Well, in that case `fields` is not a string.

Comment: @Doug you must encode every string *value* into bytes. For string values this means `value.encode('utf-8')` but for containers (like list, set, dict, etc) of strings this means going through each value an encode it, here is an example for a list: `fields = [v.encode('utf-8') for v in fields]`. Your fields variable seems to be an `object`, so there is likely some method you can call to retrieve the raw values/strings.

Comment: @nitely Thank you so much. I'm beginning to follow properly here. So, I need to encode the actual string value into bytes. Per your example, would my code 'latent_vars = [v.encode('utf-8') for v in latent_vars' be correct? And I would do that prior to making my dictionary? And you suggest a method to retrieve the values/strings for 'fields'? Is that a built-in python method or it should be a method somewhere in this guys code?

Comment: @Doug `latent_vars` is an array of integers, so it's fine as it's. All values except `fields` seem to be arrays of integers. Sadly, the code does not show where `fields` is set, so we have no way to tell what type it's. Since the error lead you to an unicode error, my guess it that it's an array of unicode strings, which needs conversion as shown in my previous comment. You would do that prior to making the dictionary. If it's a nmpy array of strings you may want to try [this instead](https://github.com/h5py/h5py/issues/289#issuecomment-329853651)

Comment: @nitely Again, I can't thank you enough for the direction. I didn't want to place the full code in the post, but it's here if you have time to take a look: https://github.com/davidsandberg/facenet/blob/master/src/generative/calculate_attribute_vectors.py   There's a method called 'read_annotations' so I suspect I should do the encode there?

Comment: @Doug according to that code [field is a regular python list of unicode strings](https://github.com/davidsandberg/facenet/blob/master/src/generative/calculate_attribute_vectors.py#L164), meaning `fields = [v.encode('utf-8') for v in fields]` prior creating the dictionary should work, if it does not, then there is another issue besides that one.

Comment: @nitely  That was it!  I will mark this as correct so you can collect the bounty and then clean-up this thread.

Comment: @Doug cheers! I'll create my answer then.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/strings.html), every string value must be encoded into byte-strings. For string values this means `value.encode('utf-8')` but for containers (mainly lists and tuples) of strings this means going through each value and encoding it.

In this case the value `fields` is a list of (unicode) strings. So, the solution is converting it into a list of byte-strings:

```
# ...
fields = [v.encode('utf-8') for v in fields]
mdict = {'latent_vars':latent_vars, 'attributes':attributes, 'fields':fields, 'attribute_vectors':attribute_vectors}
# ...
```

The rest of variables are numpy arrays of integers so they are ok.

Comment: Thank you. I think most of my issue was how I was writing the conversion syntax. Hopefully someone adds a fix in the h5py repo to avoid having to encode like this.